# Can a Djinn Illuminatus make me draw my whole deck with Ancestral Visions?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Djinn Illuminatus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDjinn%20Illuminatus%5d) in play and an [Ancestral Vision](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAncestral%20Vision%5d) comes off suspend can I draw three cards as many time as I like by paying 0 for the replicate cost?

Djinn Illuminatus

> Each instant and sorcery spell you cast has replicate. The replicate cost is equal to its mana cost. (When you cast it, copy it for each time you paid its replicate cost. You may choose new targets for the copies.)

Ancestral Vision

> Suspend 4—Blue (Rather than cast this card from your hand, pay Blue and exile it with four time counters on it. At the beginning of your upkeep, remove a time counter. When the last is removed, cast it without paying its mana cost.)
>   Target player draws three cards.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Can downvoters please explain their votes with a comment, this seems just as good a rules question as the 50 others I have asked here.

Comment: My guess is that the downvotes are because the question can be answered by the Gatherer rulings for Ancestral Vision.  Djinn Illuminatus is even called out by name.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus That is possible, but I've seen plenty of well-received (or at least neutrally-received) questions where the answer was given clearly in the Gatherer rulings. A lot of users who ask MTG questions here don't even know about the Gatherer website.

Comment: @GendoIkari Part of the problem with this question is the lack of information in it. Including the text of both cards in question rather then depending on someone either knowing them or clicking on the gatherer link would have helped with the reception. Ideally you should be able to get most of the information you need for the question without having to click on links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this will not work. You cannot pay the replicate cost that Djinn Illuminatus adds to Ancestral Visions. Ancestral Visions has an unpayable mana cost, and Djinn Illuminatus says

> Each instant and sorcery spell you cast has replicate. **The replicate cost is equal to its mana cost.**

So, the replicate cost is also unpayable.

Answer (score 7):

From the Gatherer rulings on Ancestral  Vision:

> This has no mana cost, which means its mana cost can’t be paid for effects such as replicate from Djinn Illuminatus or flashback from Snapcaster Mage.